# how could I separate items in one cell of an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

Is there any way to  separate items in one cell of an arraylist ? when I print my array list it looks like this :

```
[4485,8765,7665,76545,6544,66544,43332,2222 ....]
[8833,8383,38383,39595,49596,60696,50505,...]
.
.
.
```

so I think that it save many items in one cell while I want to save them separately. now how can I divide items in one cell and save them separately?
( the arraylist save packets received from udp )

Comment: poor explanation. Improve writing questions

Comment: Can't understand a thing of what you're saying. Please explain clearly, try to include code samples and use standard terminologies like `arrays` instead of cells.

Comment: It seems that each packet is an array of numbers itself. You will have to iterate through the array of each packet received, and insert the elements of each packet separately

Comment: How the the `ArrayList<T>` is declared - more specifically what is generic type (T) declared for `ArrayList`?

Comment: thanks , yeah each packet is an array itself , but is it possible to separate them in arraylist ?

Comment: What do you mean by "separate them"? Do you want a list containing all elements of all packets?

Comment: now each elements of the arraylist contains many numbers ! I want to separate them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `List` is declared this way:

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

You can simply iterate it.

```
for(List<Integer> integers : list) {
    System.out.println(integers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    ArrayList<Integer> arr=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    arr.add(121);
    arr.add(122);
    arr.add(123);
    arr.add(124);
    arr.add(125);


    List<Integer> l=arr;
    for(int i=0;i<l.size();i++)
   {
    System.out.println(l.get(i));
   }


  }
```